# What is the preferred way to pass data from a Rails view to a react component in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-props

I know that the `react_on_rails` and the `react-rails` gems have ways of passing data to react components. For example, you can do things like this: `<%= react_component("HelloWorld", props: @some_props) %>`.

Now that we can do `rails new myapp --webpack=react` and have `javascript packs`, how can I pass data, or props, from my rails views to my react components? Can I do something like: `<%= javascript_pack tag 'hello_react', data: @users %>`?

I don't want to have to build out an api, and it seems there isn't a preferred way to accomplish what I want. The only feasible method I have seen so far was in [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-get-your-rails-data-into-your-react-component-with-webpacker-647dc63706c9) article.

Comment: it's either to use that or use react_rails https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way is by using [react_rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)

in rails 6 the steps is first you need to add react rails

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'react-rails'
```

then run the generator `rails generate react:install`

if you not yet install webpacker/rails you need to do that first

```
rails webpacker:install
rails webpacker:install:react
rails generate react:install
```

then generate your first react component with the generator

```
rails g react:component HelloWorld greeting:string
```

next render it in your html.erb with the view_helper from the gem

```
<%= react_component("HelloWorld", { greeting: "Hello from react-rails." }) %>
```

first parameter is the react files name and the second is the props